# Xlsxwriter can't set border width

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to set the cell's border width in an Excel file using `XlsxWriter`, but I could not find a call for it in the API. I'm looking for a solution similar to using this menu:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cell border can be changed by changing border style via `set_border` on a format class:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('output.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_border(style=1)

worksheet.write('A1', "Hello, world!", format=format)

workbook.close()
```

Also see [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/format.html#set_border).

UPD: I think you cannot currently change cell border width directly from xlsxwriter.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, I'm sorry but I meant cell's border width. I've rephrased

Comment: @shevski you are welcome - I've edited the answer, please check.

Comment: I think this is the default style for them

Comment: I've edited the answer. please check. You can change the border style, but I think you cannot change cell border width currently. Consider switching to `openpyxl` if it is critical for you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't set the border width separately; it's tied to the border style index.  See the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/format.html#format-set-border).  For example, try index 2 or 5 for continuous border of weight 2 or 3, respectively.